# Cucumber and DELETE with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, mongoid

So, I am currently trying to test a Rails app wired up with Mongoid with Cucumber. I have everything setup (or so I believe) so that the following test will run:

```
Feature: Create and manage about entries
  In order to use the about data effectively
  As an application consumer
  I want to create and manage some about entries

  Scenario: Create about entries
    Given the following abouts exist
      | title             |   body_copy   |
      | "About entry #1"  | "hello body!" |
    When I go to the list of about entries
    Then I should see "About entry #1"

  Scenario: Create and retreive specific about entry
    Given the following abouts exist
      | id                        | title             |   body_copy   |
      | 4e4d37756ea257f031000003  | "About entry #1"  | "hello body!" |
    When I go to about entry with id 4e4d37756ea257f031000003
    Then I should see "About entry #1"
```

In my paths file, I have the following entries to support the above tests:

```
when /^the list of about entries$/i
  '/abouts'
when /^about entry with id (.+)$/i
  "/abouts/#{$1}"
```

These tests work great. However, I need to test the delete action. I did some research online but everything seems to be going through the UI to delete these items and the problem I have is that my Rails app only serves JSON files and JSON files and I need a better (more programatic) way of testing things without the UI being involved. As far as mocks goes, I am using the default mocks built into Pickle. I am open to using other mocking software if necessary such as factory-girl, but you'll have to give me some detailed feedback how I can wire that up. What I have currently for my delete test (that DOESN'T work) is:

```
  Scenario: Delete about
    Given the following abouts exist
      | title   | body_copy    |
      | title 1 | body_copy 1  |
      | title 2 | body_copy 2  |
      | title 3 | body_copy 3  |
      | title 4 | body_copy 4  |
    When I delete the 3rd about
    Then I should see the following abouts:
      | Title   | body_copy    |
      | title 1 | body_copy 1  |
      | title 2 | body_copy 2  |
      | title 4 | body_copy 4  |
```

The problem is that the auto-generated test (seen above) uses the `click_link "Destroy"` method call but that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the implementation of the delete step (in your web_steps.rb if your using the Cucumber generated defaults) to send a DELETE HTTP request. I'd recommend the RestClient gem for this, but there are plenty other choices.

The Cucumber Book currently in beta from PragProg has a chapter about using Cucumber to test REST APIs like this.

Comment: To send an HTTP DELETE request would require me to have the rails server running. I'm not that familiar with Rails testing, so are you saying that it is already the case when I run my tests and a rails instance is also running? An example of the step definition would be extremely helpful. Thanks!